# PHP Verificar/Derrubar Duplicidade de Login Session

Tags: php, session

Há alguma ferramenta ou algo do tipo para verificar se está ocorrendo login do mesmo usuário em dois locais diferente e derrubar o login mais antigo?

Exemplo: Eu estou logado no sistema em PHP que utilizar session para verificação de autenticidade, então uma outra pessoa que possui minha senha loga no sistema. Dai o sistema irá automaticamente me derrubar do sistema e deixar somente o novo login utilizando o sistema. Para tentar garantir que não UM ÚNICO login esteja logado no sistema em duas máquinas diferentes.

Comment: Essa pergunta é bem ampla na verdade, depende muito de como está a arquitetura do seu software, mas deve haver alguma classe ou biblioteca que te ajude a implementar regras de múltiplo login no seu sistema

Comment: Se você tiver a sessão guardada na base de dados dá sim. Eu faço isso sempre que alguém faz login apago todas as sessões existentes desse utilizador na BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, ao menos nativamente não existe, o que pode fazer é salvar no banco de dados qual a sessão ativa, inclusive pode utilizar o `session_set_save_handler` para tal ou pode criar o seu próprio sistema de gerenciamento de sessões.

---

Um "caminho das pedras" seria:

**Quando o usuário conectar:**

```
if($senhaCorreta && $tudoOk){
```

```
$idSessao = session_id();

$AtualizaSessao = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE tabela 
                                     SET idSessao = ? 
                                       WHERE idUsuario = ?');

$AtualizaSessao->bind_param('si', $idSessao, $idUsuario);
$AtualizaSessao->execute();

//...

$_SESSION['idUsuario'] = $idUsuario;
```

```
}
```

Isso irá atualizar o `idSessao` com o `id` da sessão atual, o valor do cookie.

**Agora você pode simplesmente comparar:**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['idUsuario'])) {

    $BuscaUltimaSessao = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ultimaSessao
                                            FROM tabela
                                             WHERE idUsuario = ?');

    $BuscaUltimaSessao->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['idUsuario']);
    $BuscaUltimaSessao->execute();

    $BuscaUltimaSessao->bind_result($idSessao);
    $BuscaUltimaSessao->fetch();

    if (hash_equals(session_id(), $idSessao) === false) {

        session_destroy();

        echo 'Esta sessão expirou';

    } else {

        echo 'OK';

    }

} else {

    echo 'Não há sessão';

}
```

A lógica é bem simples, somente uma sessão estará no banco de dados, na coluna `idSessao`, portanto quando o mesmo usuário conectar em outro local esta coluna será atualizada para o valor da cookie correspondente. Isso pode ser testado inclusive em navegadores diferentes, assim que se conectar em um e se conectar no outro o primeiro será desconectado após atualizar a página.

---

> **/!\ Isto possui falhas!**

Obviamente você deveria de verificar mais coisas além do cookie. Como o IP, o  navegador (...). Afinal é possível duplicar o valor do cookie, isto está do lado do cliente, assim dois dispositivos distintos podem compartilhar o mesmo cookie e assim conectar na mesma conta, *inclusive isto é um método de ataque*. Entretanto é possível que dois dispositivos estejam usando o mesmo navegador (ou fraude essa informação) e estarem usando o mesmo IP (como por exemplo vários dispositivos usando um único proxy/VPN). Esteja ciente que **ainda existirá como dois dispositivos/navegadores/pessoas estarem na mesma conta**, sinceramente não vejo nenhuma solução para isso.

Comment: Obrigado, acho que surgiu uma luz kkkkkkkkkkk
Gostei da ideia, da para implementar dessa forma, até mesmo colocando data de login e outras coisas para tentar diminuir as falhas. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

No PHP você pode utilizar Sessions, ou seja toda a vez que o usuário efetuar o login você irá registrar a sessão.

[Documentação sobre Sessions - W3CSchool](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
  print_r($_SESSION);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Agora basta criar um algoritmo para obter a lista de sessões no servidor e aplicar justamente o conceito que você mesmo citou.

Comment: ok, só que quando o usuário loga e utiliza o sistema, nesse $_SESSION eu via PHP só pego a session dele, não das outras. Não consegui achar nada que me retornasse as sessions ativas no PHP para fazer uma comparação nem nada.

Comment: O ideal é que você armazene a sessão em uma tabela para eventuais comparações...provavelmente você tem uma tabela de usuários, adicione um campo para a sessão e recupere-as através de consultas...

Comment: Realmente o ideal é armazenar a sessão em uma tabela toda vez que o usuário efetuar o login, assim você terá uma tabela atualizada a cada login com a sessão do usuário. Sendo assim você poderá verificar usuários multi-sessão.

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931401/php-session-for-multiple-users-at-once